# what does it mean by determinant of Jacobian matrix = 0?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, jacobian

I have an example:
$$ u={x+y\over 1-xy} $$
$$ v = \tan^{-1}(x)+\tan^{-1}(y) $$
So by calculating the determinant of the Jacobian matrix I get zero. Does it mean there is no functional relationship between u and v? What does $|J|=0$ mean?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In this case, there **is** a functional relationship between $u$ and $v$: in fact $u = \tan(v)$.  Thus the transformation $(x,y) \to (u,v)$ is not invertible: there is no way to get $x$ and $y$ back from $u$ and $v$.